# Where did my Vandermonde-matrix prgram go wrong?

Tags: c++, matrix, error-handling

[Screenshot of the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smp7w.png)
I am trying to figure out why my program is not working the way it should. It is a program that is supposed to create a Vandermonde-matrix but it get is the last digits wrong and I really do not see why that`s happening. I have gone through it manually (you know, checking what the computer is doing and writing it down on a paper) and I really do not see where it is going worng.

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>


int main ()
{
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cin >> n;

    double x[m];

    for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) //fill in x-es
    {
        double f;
        std::cin >> f;
        x[l] = f;
    }


    std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat ( n , std::vector<double>( m, 0));

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++) //creat matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                mat [i][j] = pow(x[i] , j);
            }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j)
            std::cout << mat [ i ] [ j ] << " " ;

                std::cout << "\n" ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its giving the right solution.

Comment: @user1438832 Seriously? `Cause I`ve been working in codeboard and it gives me wrong outputs. I`ll send a screenshot.

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat ( m , std::vector<double>( n, 0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat ( n , std::vector<double>( m, 0));`with
`std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat ( m , std::vector<double>( n, 0));`

It will work fine

Comment: Wow, it really does wrok. But why?

Comment: earlier you were creating matrix of order n x m to store elements of matrix of order m x n. Leading to invalid memory access in for loop
For ex. m = 3 and n = 4. matrix should be of order 3 x 4. But you were creating matrix of order 4 x 3.

Comment: Haha, true. Thank you! That really helped!